# ORA-24801 illegal parameter value

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-rest-data-services

Hi I have ORACLE and ORDS installed on my local machine. there is also an application that gives an error. When opening a modal window in the application, an error appears (ORA-24801: illegal parameter value in OCI lob function) I don’t understand what this is connected with. I changed passwords and unlocked default APEX users. The lisener was also restarted but it did not help. When connecting via SQLDeveloper, the request from the modal window will work out as it should. Through the web interface it gives an error.